# Prepared SQL query time vs regular query time

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

I know, from whatever I've read, prepared statements are faster since pre-compiled cached version is used for recurring queries. My doubt is : Exactly where time is saved? I see, only the time taken in preparing a query could be saved. Even prepared statements have to do database search and so no time is saved there. Am I wrong?

Comment: Which prepared statements - Java, C#?  Also, which database?

Comment: @Eric Petroelje: Is concept of prepared statement different in C# and java?

Comment: They are pretty much same between Java and C#, but some databases and drivers handle prepared statements better than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.  The time saved by using prepared statements is generally in the database engine planning/compiling the query.

Answer (score 2):

The part of a "prepared query" that is prepared is the execution plan.  The plan tells the database how to execute the query; which indexes to use, in which order.  The execution plan also resolves any access rights.

Time is saved by building the execution plan once instead of for every query.